# Removing cap from box/turtle style roof vent

Tags: roof, vent

I have a vent on a shed roof:
[image: roof vent]

that has a huge wasp nest inside (though no wasps (at the moment), thankfully!). I can see it from the inside of the shed (not pictured).

I thought it would be easy to pop the cap off of the vent, clean out the nest, then pop it back on. However, it doesn't appear to me that the cap can be removed!? There are clips on each side that seem to be riveted:

[image: roof vent clips]

Is the only thing to do here to replace the entire vent?

Here is what it looks like from the inside - there is a mesh blocking the nest:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After buying a replacement (and replacing the vent), it seems as though indeed these do not come apart (which seems CRAZY to me!). The new one I got does NOT have a mesh on the inside though, so it seems like this particular problem cannot happen again (as there's no "floor" for a nest to rest upon). However, that also means much bigger bugs can enter the shed :). I may add my own mesh on the inside of the roof, which would keep out the bugs but also allow me to remove the mesh to fix a problem like this in the future.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty rare that you'd need to open these. Some homes have a dozen or more, so the cost associated with a removable design isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you get to the nest from inside the shed? Any chance those clips can be pulled away from the rest of the vent? Replacing the vent would be the last thing I'd want to do. 
Go into the shed with a hose and just blast the nest apart. Bring  a bucket up there with you to catch the majority of the water.

Comment: there are two rivets from the clip to the cylinder, and one rivet from the clip to the cap - nothing seems to be able to be pulled away. From inside the shed there is a mesh (seems to be part of the vent, not something added on the shed side) blocking access to the nest. Man it seems like blasting it apart would make an awful mess...

Comment: Maybe "blasting" is a little harsh. Spray it a few times and maybe it will dislodge

Comment: I went ahead and replaced the vent (it was only $7 haha). Annoyingly the ones at the hardware store had a diamond pattern that needed to be cut into the shingles where the old one was a circle, so I don't know how well my futzing around with the shingles went... I guess I'll see when it rains!

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably cut away the mesh and clean out the nest, then simply fit new screen in place. You should be able to cut a rectangle slightly larger than the opening in the roof boards and simply tuck it between the boards and the vent plate.